# Decrypting a .gpg file with python

Tags: gnupg, ctl

I try to decrypt a gpg file using this command :

> gpg --batch --passphrase=*** --output file.csv --decrypt file.gpg

but it doesn't work, i can't read the content.

And would anyone know how to convert a CTL file to csv or text?

can someone help me ?

Comment: Please post the full output of your not-working gpg command.

Comment: I don't get an error message, it's when I open the file the problem, it's still encrypted

Comment: My guess: The file is correctly decrypted. And what you got is not directly a CSV file, but maybe a compressed CSV file. Check with the `file file.csv` command what kind of file it is, probably a zip or gzip compressed one.